# Why do I have to authenticate and obtain a new token again after pulling data for some months with googleAnalyticsR from Google Analytics?

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-oauth

For a customer project I am pulling from data from Google Analytics using googleAnalyticsR and googleAuthR. Setting the project up, I created an oAuth token and I had to log in to the google account with my e-mail address to confirm.

The R script that pulls the data gets automatically triggered by a windows task scheduler job every day. After a few months my customer contacted me, because the data import to the database appeared to deliver empty rows.

Running my R script manually did show the dialogue from the initial setup again:

> googleAuthR::gar_auth(token = ".httr-oauth") i 2022-01-12 09:52:02 >
> Setting client.id from options(googleAuthR.client_id) The googleAuthR
> package is requesting access to your Google account. Select a
> pre-authorised account or enter '0' to obtain a new token. Press
> Esc/Ctrl + C to cancel.
>
> 1: test@blabla.com
>
> Auswahl: ga_auth(email = "test@blabla.com") Enter an item from the
> menu, or 0 to exit Auswahl: ga_auth() Enter an item from the menu, or
> 0 to exit
>
> Auswahl:

I assumed that the token is getting a refresh automatically. Here is the part of my script that matters:

```
library(googleAnalyticsR)
library(googleAuthR)

## authenticate
googleAuthR::gar_auth(token = ".httr-oauth")
```

Comment: Refresh tokens for apps still in testing expire after seven days put your app into production

Comment: the app was set to production mode at the beginning, so there must be another reason

Comment: User revoked your access?

Comment: still got full access, but when I load the googleAnalyticsR library after reinstalling I get the message: "No consent file found". Maybe this is giving a clue. Just cannot find anything about this on the web

Comment: I just found out, that Google changed the authentication method. My former used httr file approach does not work anymore. I need to recreate the project and generate a json file for authentication. Also my R script needs to altered